# Remove multiple whitespaces by single space in a python list

Tags: python, list, replace

In Python, I have a list like `["HELLO   MR    GOOD     SOUL"]`. How can I replace multiple spaces with a single space, to get `["HELLO MR GOOD SOUL"]`?

Comment: Do you mean the _literal_ strings `"< SPACE >"` or do you mean actual (white-)spaces, as in `" "`?

Comment: I mean actual whitespaces " "

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The code formatting shows spaces, so there is no need or reason to show them like that. I [edit]ed the post to fix that, and also explain the problem more simply and directly. Anyway, please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a regular expression for this:

```py
s = "HELLO     MR      GOOD    SOUL"
re.sub(r"\s+", " ", s)
```

`\s` is whitespace, `+` means one or more. Since Regex is greedy by default, the pattern `\s+` will match as many consecutive spaces as possible.

The output:

```
'HELLO MR GOOD SOUL'
```

If you actually have a list of strings, you can do a simple list comprehension:

```py
list_of_strings = [...]
[re.sub(r"\s+", " ", s) for s in list_of_strings]
```

If you want to do it in-place:

```py
for idx, s in enumerate(list_of_strings):
    list_of_strings[idx] = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", s)
```

Comment: I did try :
list_of_strings = [...]
[re.sub(r"\s+", " ", s) for s in list_of_strings]
print(list_of_strings)

But when I print, it prints the original list and not the modified list

Comment: @Rookie well, the list comprehension creates a new list. You need to assign it to a variable.

Comment: Is there a way to do in-place assignment to the same variable?

Comment: You can just reassign `list_of_strings` to the new list if you don't need to modify the actual object. Or you can assign to the `[:]` slice of that list. Or you can use an explicit `for` loop with `enumerate`.

Comment: @Rookie I added it to my answer